# Creating the One True USB drive: Live OS + File store?

Tags: storage, encryption, usb-flash-drive, usb-boot

I'm trying to create the ultimate everyday carry USB drive that does both of these things:

1. USB Live OS (ideally Linux Tails)
2. Regular USB data store (ideally encrypted)

Another ideal: this USB stick would work in all three major operating systems (macOS, Windows, Linux) for both booting to Tails and the data store. I could partition the drive into two (or more) but see caveats below.

I can do #1 easily enough (created via Tails Installer on Ubuntu), but when the USB is plugged into a Mac it's not recognized at all as a file system—Disk Utility sees it but it can't be mounted. I haven't even tried booting from it yet. Also, Tails Installer wants to format the entire drive, not install itself to a partition.

#2 is really simple: just use it as a regular USB drive (and as long as I stay in Mac land, I can have the whole drive encrypted). If you install Tails and turn on the encrypted persistent store you can also use that as an encrypted file store in other Linux hosts, but nowhere else.

There's almost an ideal file system across all three OSes ([Universal Disk Format](https://j0nam1el.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/sharing-a-hardflash-drive-across-windows-os-x-and-linux-with-udf/)) but you can't format this on a *partition* of a USB drive without losing access in macOS (if you format the entire drive with it, it's fine). There are plenty of file system extensions you can install on the Mac to get ext3/4 and NTFS compatibility, but ideally I want to be able to sit down at anyone's computer and just use the drive with no installations on the host OS.

I live in Mac land these days, but I'm thinking about the future where I'm an international spy on the run and have to get the latest intel to my handler—I may find myself in hostile territory, ie. a room full of PCs.

Comment: Have you tried Unetbootin and FAT?